# Replacing empty strings in a specific column (1-liner)

Tags: regex, perl, text

I have a 6-column tab-delimited .txt file; the 6th column can often contain an empty string:

```
1   ARS 10  36  .   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  .   TTT 
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT ARGF10
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT
```

Wherever $F[6] is empty, I wish to insert "DUB":

```
1   ARS 10  36  .   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  .   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT ARGF10
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT DUB
```

I've tried to do this by using `if` and `else`:

```
perl -lane '($dub) = "DUB", print "$F[0]\t$F[1]\t$F[2]\t$F[3]\t$F[4]\t$F[5]\t$dub\n" if $F[6] =~ "" else print "$F[0]\t$F[1]\t$F[2]\t$F[3]\t$F[4]\t$F[5]\t$F[6]\n"'
```

However this returns the error:

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near """ else"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Why is this happening? I am also not sure how to go about matching empty strings.

Secondly, is there a better way to do conditional "find and replace" operations within 1-liners? For example if $F[6] is empty, replace the contents of $F[2] with "X".

**EDIT**:

Is there a way to make this replacement conditional? e.g. only do it when column 5 = '+':

```
1   ARS 10  36  .   TTT
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  +   TTT DUB
1   ARS 10  36  .   TTT
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT ARGF10
1   ARS 10  36  -   TTT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this(Add field separator according to your need):

```
 perl -lane '$_.="DUB" unless($F[6]);print'
```

**Edit:**

```
perl -lane '$_.="DUB" unless $F[6] || $F[4] ne "+";print'
```

I will say use this to avoid confusion in future:

```
perl -lane '$_.="DUB" if (!$F[6] and $F[4] eq "+");print'
```

Comment: Works well. How could I make this conditional? i.e. Replace the empty string with "DUB" if the 5th column contains "+"?

Comment: Show more data.Anyway same way check for 5th column i.e `$F[5]`

Comment: See OP EDIT for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

`$, = "\t"` will add tab char between list elements when printing,

```
perl -lane'
  BEGIN { $, = "\t" }
  push @F, "DUB" if @F <6 and $F[4] eq "+";
  print @F;
'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 'print join "\t", @F[0..5], $F[6] ? $F[6] : $f[5] eq "+" ? "DUB" : ""' input.txt
```